# Proving that an arbitrary function is continuous (via topological methods)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Consider the following applications:
$$f:(X,d)\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R^2},d_u)$$
$$\pi_i:(\mathbb{R^2},d_u)\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R},d_u)$$
Where $f$ is an arbitrary function, $\pi_i$ is the projection on the $i$-th component, that is, $\pi_1(a,b)=a$ and $\pi_2(a,b)=b$, and $d_u$ is the euclidean metric.

> Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\pi_i\circ f$ is
>   continuous for each $i={1,2}$.

Now, I've already done the easy part. If $f$ is continuous, since the projections are also continuous, and the composition of continuous functions is continuous, then $\pi_i\circ f$ is also continuous for each $i$.

But, reciprocally, what if we assume that those 2 compositions are continuous. How can we then prove that $f$ is continuous?

I'm not sure if its necessary to use the fact that they are metric spaces, or if that works for any topological space, in which case we should be able to prove it just by using the notions of neighbourhoods and open sets.

Comment: What metric is $d_u$?

Comment: It's the usual, euclidean metric.

Comment: What is a "generic" function? Do you mean "arbitrary"? "Generic" in mathematics often means something like "with probability 1" or "on a set of measure 1." So a generic function is not continuous, since most functions are not continuous.

Comment: Oh sorry, I indeed meant arbitrary. Corrected ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for any topological spaces $Y,Z$, where $f:X\to Y\times Z$. Assume $\pi_Y\circ f$ and $\pi_Z\circ f$ are both continuous. Notice that to prove continuity it is enough to prove that the inverse image of any open **basic** sets is open, so take $U=U_Y\times U_Z$ a basic open. We have:
$$\begin{array}{ll}f^{-1}(U)&=f^{-1}(\pi_Y^{-1}(U_Y)\cap\pi^{-1}_Z(U_Z))\\&=f^{-1}(\pi_Y^{-1}(U_Y))\cap f^{-1}(\pi_Z^{-1}(U_Y))\\&=(\pi_Y\circ f)^{-1}(U_Y)\cap(\pi_Z\circ f)^{-1}(U_Z)\end{array}$$
and thus it is open as it is the intersection of two open sets by assumption. Notice that the same reasoning works also for the infinite dimensional case (so long as you take the product topology, obviously).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the clear explanation ;) By the way, where in that reasoning is the hypothesis of $U$ being basic being used?

Comment: @LMartin You're welcome :) The assumption of $U$ being basic is used in the fact that we take $U=U_Y\times U_Z$.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks ;)